# How do I set the default icons to my own choice instead of Yaru?

Tags: gnome, icons, themes

as per the title;
I want to have my own icon set `(Win10Sur-black-dark)` instead of Ubuntu's default, Yaru.

After getting the icons from my drive `(I have it there as backup)` and setting them in Gnome Tweaks, everything was fine. Until I rebooted when it just reverted back to Yaru.

What do I do? Thanks!

Edit: I just needed to change the shell to *Default* instead of *Yaru-dark*.

Comment: Still - could you share your Ubuntu version? It might help others...

Comment: Oh, right. 22.04 LTS, recently upgraded from Fedora 35.

Comment: Apparently the new Style setting overrides user icon themes. Is this a feature or a bug?

Comment: No one knows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to change your custom icons is not exposed to the user in a default Ubuntu install. You need to install an additional tool, Gnome Tweaks, where you can change to another correctly installed icon theme on the "Appearance" tab:

[image]

Comment: that's how I did it. Ubuntu doesn't install GTweaks by default, so use `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` to achieve that.

Comment: Yeah, it’s the best (and only) answer there is, so you get the green checkmark.